# apple apns server max can take how many request in 10 minute?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

my application send out 10k of request to APNS server in ~10 mins and non of them reach my clients. any idea ? is there a max cap?

By upgrade my developer account from 'Individual' to 'company' account, can solve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

issue solved. my program halt due to memory not enough. i separate them to few schedule task.

Answer (score 1):

Do you send them all in one connection or do you make 10,000 separate requests to the APNS servers?  Can you post some code?

No problem sending that many as I do.

It is also in no way linked to whether you have an individual or company account either.